# connect to FTP using array values

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and struggling to get the data from a table in mysql and using it to connect to an ftp server. The table contains the external ip address of the ftp server, the base directory to change into and login credentials to use. I fetched the data from mysql and stored it in an array  but while looping through it I get

> php notice: trying to access array offset on type null.

Code:

```
    $now = time();
    $yesterday = $now - (24 * 60 * 60);
    $date = date("Y-m-d", $yesterday);
    if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
       $date = $_GET['date'];
    }
    
    $startDate = "$date 00:00:00";
    $endDate = "$date 23:59:59";
    
    //$conn = &newEtConn();
    
    $sql= "SELECT stager_usr, stager_pwd, stager_ip, basedir, view_direction from  et_devices.cameras as a inner join  et_params.stagers as  b on a.stagerid = b.idstagers ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $datas = array();
    if (!$result) {
             die ("table Connection problem");
    }
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $datas[] =  $row;
    }
    print_r($datas);
    }
     if ($row!= "") {
    foreach ($datas as $values) {
    $ip_addr = $values['stager_ip'];
    $login  = $values['stager_usr'];
    $password = $values['stager_pwd'];
    $basedir  = $values['basedir'];
    if ($rows != "") {
    $gotFtpConn = True;
    $ftp_obj = ftp_connect($ip_addr, 21, 10) or $gotFtpConn = False;

    if ($gotFtpConn) {
        if (ftp_login($ftp_obj, $login, $passwd)) {
           echo "could not connect" . $login;
           return false;
     }

     return  $newEtConn;
   } 
 }
}
```

Comment: Loop through the`$datas` and access whatever you need to connect to your ftp.

Comment: i tried to do that , but how do you call the ipaddress on ftp connection

Comment: I have edited my code please check

Comment: The code does not appear to be complete. Based on a `return` that I see, I think it is either a function or a method. Although we always want a minimal amount of code, it still needs to be valid. You also have at least three apparent questions, how to get data out of a database, how to connect to an FTP server, and how to list files from a dynamically named folder on an FTP server. Each of these should probably be addressed independently.

Comment: thanks Chris , I will raise  other questions independently. but to this question i got the data out of database to  an array but  i need the array to be used to be  connected to ftp. This is where I am struck

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that I don't like (and can improve)...

It looks like you intend to filter your database data based on a date, but then you never actually apply that value to the array.  I'll help to clean up that process.

Your `if ($row != '')` check after the loop will always fail because the loop ONLY stops when `$row` becomes falsey.

The rest of your code looks like it only intends to process a single row in the result set (because it `return`s).  I am going to assume that you have more conditional logic in your query's `WHERE` clause which ensures that only one row is returned -- otherwise, you shouldn't be using `return` in your loop.

```
$date = !empty($_GET['date']) && preg_match('/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/', $_GET['date'])
    ? $_GET['date']
    : date('Y-m-d', strtotime('yesterday'));

$sql = "SELECT stager_usr, stager_pwd, stager_ip
        FROM et_devices.cameras AS a
        JOIN et_params.stagers AS b ON a.stagerid = b.idstagers
        WHERE DATE(a.some_datetime_column) = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $date);
$stmt->execute();

foreach ($stmt->get_result() as $row) {
    $ftp = ftp_connect($row['stager_ip'], 21, 10);
    if (!$ftp) {
        throw new Exception('Failed to establish FTP connection');
    }
    if (!ftp_login($ftp, $row['stager_usr'], $row['stager_pwd'])) {
        throw new Exception('Incorrect FTP login credentials');
    }
    return $ftp;
}
throw new Exception('FTP connection data not found');
```

If you experience a noticeable performance bottleneck with `DATE()` in your sql, then there are other techniques that may be faster, but they use longer/uglier syntax.

Comment: thanks  mick,  I can get to the ftp login now  ,but there is no date column on the table, I  have 2 tables which got servername, serverip, and serverpasssword   and i got base directory in another table .  But on FTP server there is csv file create for that particular date and i need to get that csv  file. now I get the error   no datetime column defined.  sorry for being a noob

Comment: i dont have datetime  column and  I cant use where clause as there is no datetime defined. now i get number of variables does not match no od parametres in prepared statment

Comment: Why is there `$date` in your question at all then?

Comment: mick,  I want to use the date  variable  to fetch the  file when once connected to |FTP , so that i can got to yesterdays folder on ftp and get the file

Comment: I don't see the logic that guarantees that only one row is returned from the query.  Are you intending to return one ftp connection resource or multiple. What is this code `return`ing to?   I don't see where your code tries to fetch the directory's files.  Your code is so flawed that I cannot extrapolate what your intent is.